# Discord python bot: AttributeError: Can't pickle local object

Tags: python, class, pickle, attributeerror, discord.py

Hello, I'm trying to multiprocess my discord bot with a master class that create workers and retrieve discord messages to put them in a queue. When I initialize my workers i pass as argument my discord client, here is the error.

```py
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'WeakSet.__init__.<locals>._remove'
```

My code:

```py
class Master:
    def __init__(self):
        # Vars init
        print('Starting Master...')
        self.client = discord.Client()
        self.manager = Manager()
        self.user_spam = self.manager.dict()
        self.user_mute_chat = self.manager.dict()
        self.forbidden_words_list = []
        self.spam_t = self.manager.Value('i', 0)
        self.user_t_spam_muted = self.manager.Value('i', 0)
        self.to_master = []
        self.request_queue = Queue()
        self.cpu = cpu_count()

        # Web socket handlers
        # self.client.event(self.on_member_update)
        self.client.event(self.on_ready)
        self.client.event(self.on_message)

        # Bot init
        self.forbidden_words_list = self.manager.list(get_file_content('res/forbidden_words.txt'))
        for line in get_file_content('res/settings.txt'):
            if 'spamtime=' in line:
                self.spam_t = int(line.replace('spamtime=', ''))
            if 'usertimemuted' in line:
                self.user_t_spam_muted = int(line.replace('usertimemuted=', ''))

        # Workers init
        print('Starting Workers...')
        for i in range(self.cpu):
            Worker(self.request_queue, self.client, self.user_spam, self.user_mute_chat, self.spam_t,
                   self.user_t_spam_muted, self.forbidden_words_list).start()

        # Discord init
        print('Connecting to discord...')
        self.client.run(TOKEN)

class Worker(Process):
    def __init__(self, queue, client, user_spam, user_mute_chat, spam_t, user_t_spam_muted, forbidden_words_list):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        # Vars init
        self.client = client
        self.message = ''
        self.message_id = discord.Message
        self.word_list = []
        self.username = discord.Member
        self.queue = queue
        self.user_spam = user_spam
        self.user_mute_chat = user_mute_chat
        self.spam_t = spam_t
        self.user_t_spam_muted = user_t_spam_muted
        self.forbidden_words_list = forbidden_words_list

    async def run(self):
        # do some initialization here

        # Work here
        for data in iter(self.queue.get, None):
            pass
```

Full traceback :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PC/PycharmProjects/AIDiscord/AIDiscord.py", line 406, in <module>
    master = Master()
  File "C:/Users/PC/PycharmProjects/AIDiscord/AIDiscord.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.user_t_spam_muted, self.forbidden_words_list).start()
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'WeakSet.__init__.<locals>._remove'
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x0EDDAED0>
```

I searched a little more and it append when I start() processes, it is not dependant of arguments I passed.

Comment: Show the full traceback.

Comment: Full traceback is added

Comment: There's some discussion [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue29517) that looks relevant but I don't really understand what's going on myself. You might have run into a bug but since the issue was closed it seems not. async objects seem to be a problem. What if you remove the `async` from `def run`?

Comment: I can't remove async, my methods : filter_chat_words() and spam_detection() use async cause of discord.py
I tryed to remove it and I still get the same error

Comment: I've been around 6 hours on the problem without getting any solutions...

Comment: I guess the problem is about passing self.client as attribute when starting Worker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the instances of your asyncio loop and related items in `multiprocessing.Process.run` instead of init.

The pattern I use is something like:

```py
import asyncio
import multiprocessing
import typing


class Process(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self,
                 group=None,
                 target=None,
                 name=None,
                 args=(),
                 kwargs=None):
        super().__init__(group, target, name, args, kwargs)
        self.loop: typing.Optional[asyncio.AbstractEventLoop] = None
        self.stopped: typing.Optional[asyncio.Event] = None

    def run(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.stopped = asyncio.Event()
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self._run())
    
    async def _run(self):
        """My async stuff here"""
```

Answer (score 0):

The multiprocessing library tries to pickle the necessary objects. However, you are using Asyncio (the "run" method in the "worker" class) and it causes this error.

> you can not pickle Asyncio objects in Python.