# How to use websockets server in a thread and properly close the thread and shut down event loop?

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket

My design is probably wrong here but I'll ask anyway. Currently, I am using websockets to create a websocket server. I am performing a lot of other work in my program and would like the websocket server to be in its own thread. I create a class that subclasses threading.Thread and overrides the run method. This class's stop method is where I close the websocket server, and stop & close the event loop that I created.

```
class MyWsServer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, address, port):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.port = port
        self.address = address
        self.server = None
        self.running = False
        self.loop = None

    def start_ws_server(self):
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        if not self.loop:
            self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        ws_server = websockets.serve(self.ws_handler, self.address, self.port,
                                     ping_timeout=None, ping_interval=None, loop=self.loop)
        self.running = True
        self.server = ws_server
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self.server)
        self.loop.run_forever()

    def stop_ws_server(self):
        self.running = False
        self.server.ws_server.close()
        self.loop.stop()
        self.loop.close()

    async def ws_handler(self, websocket, path):
        while self.running:
            print(self.running)
            # simulate work
            print("doing some work")
            sleep(5)
            print("Sending data")
            data = json.dumps({"test": "test test"})
            try:
                await websocket.send(data)
                result = await websocket.recv()
                print(result)
                result = json.loads(result)
                print(f"json: {result}")
            except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
                print(f"Terminated")
                break
        print("out of ws_handler")
```

This class instance is accessible elsewhere in the program and when calling the stop() method, I get the following error regarding self.loop.close(). Nothing further up in the stack trace is worth noting.

```
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 674, in close
    raise RuntimeError("Cannot close a running event loop")
RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop
```

So my questions are:

1. Why doesn't self.loop.stop() stop the event loop?
2. Is there a better solution for stopping the event loop and the endgoal, stopping the thread?

Also just to note, I don't think setting self.running to False in stop_ws_server() does anything since this thread should be stuck on `result = await websocket.recv()` the majority of the time. I don't seem to have a clean way to exit the websocket handler. The last three lines in stop_ws_server() seem rather bruteforce-ish to me.

I've also seen some post on Stack Overflow and regarding asyncio objects and them not being threadsafe as well as plenty of posts recommending some sort of usage for asyncio's loop.call_soon_threadsafe(). I'm not sure I how I can use that with my current setup though.

Well, I greatly appreciate any help. Thanks. Please let me know if things could need more clarification.

Comment: Not a complete answer, but I have some code like this (which runs a websocket server event loop) in a thread, in this case for use in tests.  It's a bit of a snake nest (might be clearer if I rewrote it as a class) but it works well: https://gitlri.lri.fr/renewal/recsystems/blob/master/renewal_recsystem/utils/testing/__init__.py#L217    It does not have a "stop" method as such, but if you set up a websocket handler that accepts a "poison pill" to stop serving, then the event loop (and hence the thread) will clean up and shut down properly.  Might give some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems quite hackish to me but I took guidance from another solution here on Stack Overflow. Here is the answer of use, https://stackoverflow.com/a/67767248/5879710. The new code is as follows. I removed some lines from the previous code as well such as now unused variables and print statements.

```
class MyWsServer(Process):
    def __init__(self, address, port):
        super().__init__()
        self.port = port
        self.address = address

    def run(self):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        ws_server = websockets.serve(self.ws_handler, self.address, self.port,
                                     ping_timeout=None, ping_interval=None, loop=loop)
        loop.run_until_complete(ws_server)
        loop.run_forever()

    async def ws_handler(self, websocket, path):
        while True:
            # simulate work
            print("doing some work")
            sleep(5)
            print("Sending data")
            data = json.dumps({"test": "test test"})
            try:
                await websocket.send(data)
                result = await websocket.recv()
                print(result)
                result = json.loads(result)
                print(f"json: {result}")
            except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
                print(f"Terminated")
                break
```

To start the process, I call start() on the WsListener class instance that I create elsewhere in the code and I call terminate() to kill the process. I would have liked a more graceful way to kill the event loop and other created resources in the process but I haven't found a better way yet.

Edit: Forgot to mention that I am using Multiprocessing now